# Do unavailable external resources affect page load times and page functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, pageload

From what I can tell, unavailable external resources do not affect page load times and page functionality. Specifically, I am building a tracking script that will be hosted on an external site. I need the calling site to still function perfectly even if the external site is down.

```
<script src="http://thissitemaybedown.com/track.js"></script>
```

If the site is down, from the testing I've done, it appears that the page will still function properly even if the above code is near the top of the page. Also,

```
((new Image()).src='http://thissitemaybedown.com/track.php?ip=..&name=..');
```

will run at various times, like when the script completes and when the page unloads.

My questions are:

1) Will the page still function properly if the external site (thissitemaybedown.com) is down?

2) Should I be loading this tracking script asynchronously, either with defer or async in the script tag, or loading it dynamically from another script tag (like Google Analytics does it), to make sure it doesn't affect the page?

I tested the above on my web server without an asynchronous load and it appeared to function (despite an error in the browser's JS console). I just want to be sure because my clients will be quite unhappy if their sites are affected negatively.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) If nothing relies on the the script, you'll be fine. But you could have problems if you use a window.onload event and the script fails. 2) Yes, load all unnecessary resources asynchronously.

Comment: Depends how down the site is. Here in China, we get many sites that are blocked, and they usually take a minute or so for each request to timeout. That makes for a seriously bad user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The page will still load even if your script fails to load. There will be an error in the browser console showing the cause of the failure. This can cause problems only when some code in the page relies on your script.
2. If there is an option to load script in async manner, you should try and do so.

Comment: Thanks! No other code in the page will rely on the script. It appears that even if I put the (new image()) with a nonexistent URL in a window.onbeforeunload function, it will still just move right along without complaining. I wonder if this is the browser's way to deal with all of the poorly written javascript? The web probably wouldn't work if pages halted on javascript errors.